# what's the appropriate Java EE technology to do a timed "cron job"?

Tags: email, jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE app on WebSphere 7.

My app places emails that need to be sent in a notifications table in the db.

I'd like to write code that fires every 5 or 10 minutes and scans the notification tables for entries with status "PENDING", sends the email, then updates the status as "SENT".

What's the appropriate Java EE technology to make this happen every 5 or 10 minutes?  Is there somekind of "timer process" available in Java EE?

Any info is useful, thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize @Schedule annotations for such purpose.

JavaEE 6 has Timer service for this

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

```
@ManagedBean
@Stateless(name="MyScheduledTaskClass")
public class MyScheduledTaskClass implements Serializable{
private Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Schedule(minute="*/5")       //minute="*/10" if you want every 10 minutes
    public void executeTask(){
        _log.info("Scheduled task started");
        //Do some stuff here
        _log.info("Scheduled task finished");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if this is available in Java EE 5?

Comment: Which server version/implementation are you using?

Comment: Based on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0707_barcia/0707_barcia.html and http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=244 your server needs to be capable of JSR-236 wich is part of JavaEE6 spec.Then why to use JavaEE5?

Comment: WebSphere 7 is Java EE 5 only, so this mechanism won't help him.

Answer (score 3):

[Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/quick-start) is a good library.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere 7 runs Java EE 5 (I think), so your choices are little bit limited in that regard.

You can use a library like [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), but you have to be careful to hook it up to a thread pool which is managed by the container. I believe by default it just creates threads on its own which is outright prohibited in EJBs (and strongly discouraged in the web container).

I found a nice blog post that walks you through the configuration of setting up a work manager pool on WebSphere: http://sanjsuya.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/asynchronousbean-was-spring-integration/

If you're using Spring, you can then hook up the Quartz scheduler to this thread pool fairly easily using a WorkManagerTaskExecutor. Here's some Spring documentation on that (note, it's from Spring 2, but I'm sure you more-or-less do something like this for Spring 3 as well): http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

EDIT: the architect in me is cringing slightly (though maybe you have a good reason for doing it the way you're doing it). Why are you writing e-mails to a DB and not to a queue? That way, they could be processed at the leisure of a receiving system, and you're not overloading a whole lot of background work onto WebSphere.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is excellent, however the Java EE spec now includes EJB timers which may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need anything very fancy, you can schedule tasks with `java.util.concurrent.Executors`

```
public class Foo implements Runnable(){

    public void run(){
    //do stuff
    }

}
```

And schedule to run every *t* milliseconds with *d* delay seconds

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Foo(), d, t, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```